# Multi languages font

Tags: image, fonts

I have a python script that takes a list of strings (from different languages - English, Chinese, Hebrew, etc) and draws the strings into image files.

The problem is that I can't find a font that can understand and mimic each one of the strings.

For example, Chinese is translated into
[image]

A working example is the browsers address bar for example - How do they keep the URL with the relevant font?

Update -
See my draw text to image code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
#Draws strings to image
for str in list:
    base = Image.open(r"path\base.png").convert('RGBA')
    txt = Image.new('RGBA', base.size, (255, 255, 255, 0))
    fnt = ImageFont.truetype('timesbi.ttf', 100)
    d = ImageDraw.Draw(txt)
    d.text((10, 10), str.decode('utf-8'), font=fnt, fill=(255, 255, 255, 128))
    print str.decode('utf-8')
    out = Image.alpha_composite(base, txt)
    out.show()
```

Comment: They use a font that has a broader selection of unicode glyphs than whatever you are using. You should post your code and ask specific questions about the problems you're encountering

Comment: I've added my code.

Comment: Rather than your code you should post an [MCVE]. But either way, what is 'timesbi.ttf'? Have you tried looking at it in your OS's font viewer? does it contain the characters you're trying to render? If not, well, they're not going to render.

Comment: The timesbi.ttd is just a test I ran. As mentioned in my post, I couldn't find any font that does the work (I ran all windows fonts). 

The question is - is there a font that able to represent all characters?

Comment: Fair enough, just turn that into an [MCVE] others can try/verify. Maybe just use some literals and the simplest thing that bitblits some text and gives you boxes.

Comment: This is really just a matter of having the right font, if you are, as in your case, just blitting fonts explicitly. Here's a variant of your code and its output. http://imgur.com/a/3esmm